# python and pip does not match in anaconda environment

Tags: pip, anaconda, conda

As illustrated in the topic:

```
which python

/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/${PROJECT}/bin/python
```

and

```
which pip

/home/ubuntu/.local/bin/pip
```

this will cause `pip install *package` failure. Package will be installed into different environment, e.g. system environment instead of `${PROJECT}` environment.

The `${PATH}` inside my venv is like:

```
/home/ubuntu/.local/bin:
/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/efficientdet/bin:
/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/condabin:
/usr/local/cuda/bin:
/usr/local/sbin:
/usr/local/bin:
/usr/sbin:
/usr/bin:
/sbin:
/bin:
/usr/games:
/usr/local/games:
/snap/bin
```

I can use `/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/${PROJECT}/bin/pip` but that' too cumbersome. Any help?

Comment: What does your `PATH` environment varaible look like when inside the venv. Do you have an `alias` set for pip?

Comment: I added the `PATH` now.

Comment: Looks odd that `/home/ubuntu/.local/bin` is at the top even though your env is activated. Are you activating the env in the `.bashrc` by any chance? Where are you adding the `/home/ubuntu/.local/bin` entry?

Comment: hmmmm, you are right. AFAIK, I didn't add `/home/ubuntu/.local/bin` manually to `.bashrc`. Before I reinstall `pip`, I indeed have a `pip` in `~/.local/bin` directory. However, it was removed after I reinstalled `pip` in the venv.

Comment: Can you share the contents of the environment?

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved, while root cause of this problem remains unclear.

```
*in your virenv*: python -m pip install --force-reinstall pip
```

then deactivate your virenv and reactivate it will solve this problem. Anyone could give a further understanding of this problem will be more than welcoming.

Comment: This is not a very good fix. `pip` should be installed when creating the environment using `conda`. Now you are removing and reinstalling it using `pip`, which is a recipe for trouble.

Comment: What's the difference between packages installed by `conda` and `pip`, do you mind giving a further explanation? I was always intended to use `pip`.

Comment: @Sherk Be careful! Do not use pip with Conda unless absolutely necessary, see for example https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment.